# django-contenttypes - List All Generic Relations for Model

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I would like to reflect on a model and list all its backward generic relations.

My model looks like this:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host)

    statuses = generic.GenericRelation(Status)
```

The Status object looks like this:

```
class Status(TrackedModel):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'statuses'
```

I would like to programatically learn that `statuses` is a generic relation for the Service model. Is this possible? `Status._meta.fields` does not show `statuses`, but `Status._meta.get_all_field_names()` does, only it shows other unwanted things too.

I thought that this might be a possible solution, but it seems really messy to me. I'd love to hear of a better one.

```
from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

generic_relations = []
for field_name in Service._meta.get_all_field_names():
    try:
        field = Service._meta.get_field(field_name)
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        continue

    if isinstance(field, generic.GenericRelation):
        generic_relations.append(field)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GenericRelation` works similarly as `ManyToManyField`. You could find it in `Service._meta.many_to_many`:

```
filter(lambda f:isinstance(f, generic.GenericRelation), Service._meta.many_to_many)
```

Comment: This was working with 1.5, but not anymore in 1.6. This is probably a bug, as we can get the field using `get_field_by_name` but not with `get_field`.

Comment: This is out of date, sadly. It appears to only be available in `Service._meta.virtual_fields` now.

Comment: `virtual_fields` is also out of date, at least for django 2.0

Comment: UPDATE 2021: `virtual_fields` is also outdated. Now it is `_meta.private_fields` to get all the  `GenericRelations()`.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2021:

To list all the `GenericRelations()` fields:

```py
print(Service._meta.private_fields)
```

Output:

```
[<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation: statuses>]
```

Nevertheless, if you have more fields with `GenericRelations()` relationship they will be shown into the output list.

Check the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.10/#id3

Or you can return all of the fields that have a `GenericRelation()` field type.

ex:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    . . .
    my_model_field = GenericRelation(OtherPolyModel)


def get_generic_relation_fields(self):
   """
   This function returns all the GenericRelation 
   fields needed to return the values that are 
   related to a polymorphic model.
   """
   fields = [f.attname for f in self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields()]
   file_fields = []
   for field in fields:
       get_type = self.Meta.model._meta.get_field(field)
       field_type = get_type.__class__.__name__
            
       if field_type == "GenericRelation":
           file_fields.append(field)

       return file_fields
```

Output:

```
['my_model_field']
```